# Two Objects with different information

Tags: powershell

When I get email delegation I do it like this

```
If ($Delegate.count -eq 0) { 
    $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        PrimaryEmail = $SourceEmail
        Delegate     = "None"
    }
    $resultsEmail += $Result
}
Else {
    Foreach ($user in $Delegate) {
        $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
            PrimaryEmail = $SourceEmail
            Delegate     = $user.DelegateAddress
        }
        $resultsEmail += $Result
    }
}
```

I would like to also get Calendar delegation and add it. The problem is it is two separate amounts of information. Either can be various amounts.

```
Foreach ($user in $DelegateCalendarl) {
        $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
            CalendarDelegateEmail = $DelegateCalendar.'scope.value'
            CalendarRole          = $DelegateCalendar.role
            CalendarDelegateType  = $DelegateCalendar.'scope.type'
        }
        $ResultsCal += $Result
```

The end out out would be a nice table like

```
PrimaryEmail | Delegate      | CalendarDelegateEmail | CalendarRole | CalendarDelegateType
user@email    Delagate@email   Delagate@email           manager          user
user@email       ""            Delagate2@email          Reader           user
```

How can I combine both Results into one nice table csv file out like this example above?
(I know how to output them separately )

Comment: How are you getting the data? It could be as simple as adding both values to one psobject

Comment: If you wanna merge both objects there has to be one correlation column, meaning, `$resultsEmail` should have a column that correlates with a column on `$resultsCal`. If his was the case, it would help if you show us how one row on each object looks like.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, by looking at your expected result, it seems it ***could*** be a correlation between `Delegate` & `CalendarDelegateEmail` however on the last row, it's not possible to logically match both columns because `Delegate` is empty, hence it would be not possible with the current information we have to merge your 2 objects.

Comment: I can key off the primary address. The idea is to get mailbox delegate and the calendar delegate for the same mailbox. So both both command that I get with have the primary mail is address.

Comment: I am using gam to get google mailbox delegate and calendar

Comment: Since they share a primary key. How do I used that to combine them?

Comment: This is what I did. I am sure it could be better but it works. I am interested in any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did. Not pretty but it works.

```
$SourceEmail = 'test@email.com'
[array]$DelegateEmail = gam user $SourceEmail print delegates | ConvertFrom-Csv
[array]$DelegateCalendar = gam calendar $SourceEmail print acls | ConvertFrom-Csv

[int]$max = $DelegateCalendar.Count
if ([int]$DelegateEmail.count -gt [int]$DelegateCalendar.count) { $max = $DelegateEmail.Count; }
 
$Output = @()
$Result = $null

If ($DelegateEmail.count -eq 0) {$mailD = "None"}
If ($DelegateEmail.count -eq 1) {$mailD = $DelegateEmail.DelegateAddress}
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++) {
    If ($DelegateEmail.count -eq 0 -and $i -ige 1) {$mailD = ""}
    If ($DelegateEmail.count -eq 1 -and $i -gt 0) {$mailD = ""}
    if ($DelegateEmail.count -gt 1) {$MailD = $DelegateEmail.DelegateAddress[$i]}

    $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        PrimaryEmail          = $SourceEmail
        DelegateEmailAddress  = $mailD
        CalendarDelegateEmail = $DelegateCalendar.'scope.value'[$i]
        CalendarRole          = $DelegateCalendar.Role[$i]
        CalendarDelegateType  = $DelegateCalendar.'scope.type'[$i]
    }
    $Output += $Result
}

$Output | Export-Csv C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Btw very annoying 
'''
$DelegateEmail.DelegateAddress[$i]
'''
Would give me 1 letters answers unless  ($i -gt 1)